# Facebook produces "An error occurred. Please try later" when handling oauth request

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth

This has been discused on SOF, though, I didn't find anyone having exactly the same problem. Furthermore, it's been more than 2 days now, so I figured to ask.

1. App is running in a sandbox. Update: the same is happening in sandbox-less environment.
2. Doesn't work regardless if I use `admin`, `developer` or `tester` account.
3. Doesn't work regardless of whether the user has authorized the app already or not.

Just before calling `$fb->getLoginError()`, the `$fb` instance dump (Facebook PHP-SDK) looks like the following:

```
object(Facebook)#85 (7) {
  ["appId:protected"]=>
  string(15) "[removed for SOF display]"
  ["apiSecret:protected"]=>
  string(32) "[removed for SOF display]"
  ["user:protected"]=>
  int(0)
  ["signedRequest:protected"]=>
  NULL
  ["state:protected"]=>
  string(32) "[removed for SOF display]"
  ["accessToken:protected"]=>
  string(48) "[removed for SOF display]"
  ["fileUploadSupport:protected"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

All the `[removed for SOF display]` information is present.

The code itself:

```
$login_url      = $fb->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => $config->facebook['scope'], 'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri ));

echo '
    <noscript>javascript must be enabled.</noscript>
    <script type="text/javascript">top.location.href = \'' . addslashes($login_url) . '\';</script>
';
```

The URL generated by getLoginUrl() is the following:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[removed for SOF display]&redirect_uri=[removed for SOF display]&scope=publish_stream%2C+email%2C+user_birthday%2C+user_interests%2C+user_likes
```

The most annoying thing is that Facebook is producing error **An error occurred. Please try later** without any additional information. I've even tried to set $login_url to something stupid like `http://google.com/` which didn't produce expected error. Just the same **An error occurred. Please try later**.

I've been developing apps for quite a while and this is the first time I am having an issue as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error turned out to be caused by the redirect URI `http://facebook.com/[..]`.

Usually, if unauthorized domain is used, Facebook produces an error that you have to add the domain to Facebook app settings, `App Domain`. In this case, it simply produces completely useless `An error occurred. Please try later`.